# Can you get the attachment filename in a for each statement on mulesoft?

Tags: mule, filenames, email-attachments

I have an email to file scenario. The email contains multiple attachments and I need to process them one by one to be passed to another flow and I need the original filename. I can get the attachment names before the for each scope but I cant use it to be the filename of the target file. Any help or suggestions will really be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:batch="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:pop3="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pop3" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pop3 http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pop3/current/mule-pop3.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch/current/mule-batch.xsd">
    <file:connector name="File" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <flow name="Knauf_Load_List">
        <pop3:inbound-endpoint host="mailhost" user="exampleuser" password="examplepass" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Poll Email PDF"/>
        <set-session-variable variableName="State" value="#[message.inboundProperties.To]" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
        <set-variable variableName="filename()" value="#[message.inboundAttachments.keySet()]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <expression-transformer doc:name="Expression">
            <return-argument evaluator="attachments-list" expression="*.pdf"/>
        </expression-transformer>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each">
            <set-payload value="#[payload.getContent()]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
            <logger message="#[flowVars.filename]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <file:outbound-endpoint path="\\HO-AWH-OCRPROD1\CustomerOrders\Knauff" outputPattern="Knauf_Bunnings_Orders-#[message.id].pdf" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
            <set-session-variable variableName="PDF" value="#[flowVars.counter]" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
        </foreach>
        <logger message="#[sessionVars.PDF] for #[sessionVars.State]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="ocr_app_test_edi_flow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="\\HO-AWH-OCRPROD1\Output\Knauff\EDIEnterprise" moveToPattern="OCR_Archive-#[server.dateTime.format('dd-MM-yy_HH-mm-ss')].xml" moveToDirectory="S:\AWHMan\IT\IT Middleware Project\Ocr To EDI Archive" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" connector-ref="File"/>
        <file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String"/>
        <set-variable variableName="order" value="#[xpath3('/Payload/WhsDockets/WhsDocket/Reference')]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="\\HO-AWH-FS6\ediEnterprise Import Files" outputPattern="Knauf-#[flowVars.order].xml" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Can you specify your problem better ? If you can get it before the foreach this means you can store them so why can't you use it after ?

Comment: Hi Mauro, I need to assign the same file name to output a file at the same time processing it in parallel to a db.

Answer (score 0):

Good,

Do not know if this will serve, but I have implemented the following code for an IMAP account:

```
    <choice doc:name="Choice between mail with and without attachments">
        <when expression="#[message.dataType.mimeType == &quot;multipart/alternative&quot;]">
            <set-variable variableName="hasAttachment" value="false" doc:name="Set hasAttachment"/>
            <set-payload value="#[message.inboundAttachments['0'].getContent()]" doc:name="Set Payload from Body"></set-payload>
            <set-variable variableName="fileName" value="" doc:name="Set fileName"/>
        </when>
        <when expression="#[message.dataType.mimeType == &quot;multipart/mixed&quot;]">
            <set-variable variableName="hasAttachment" value="true" doc:name="Set hasAttachment"/>
            <expression-transformer doc:name="Set Payload from Attachments">
                <return-argument evaluator="attachments" expression="*.*"/>
            </expression-transformer>
            <set-variable variableName="fileName" value="#[payload.keySet().iterator().next()]" doc:name="Set fileName"/>
            <set-payload value="#[payload[flowVars.fileName].getContent()]" doc:name="Set Payload from firts Attachment content"></set-payload>
            <object-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="Object to Byte Array"></object-to-byte-array-transformer>
        </when>
        <when expression="#[message.dataType.mimeType == &quot;text/plain&quot;]">
            <set-variable variableName="hasAttachment" value="false" doc:name="Set hasAttachment"/>
            <set-payload value="#[payload.getContent()]" doc:name="Set Payload from Text"/>
            <set-variable variableName="fileName" value="" doc:name="Set fileName"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <logger message="La informaci&#243;n del EMail no es v&#225;lida" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
```

As you can see in the WHEN "#[message.dataType.mimeType == "multipart/mixed"]", retrieve all the attachments and in my case the first of them I get the first value of the iterator containing the names of the attachments:

```
#[payload.keySet().iterator().next()]
```

With this name you can directly access the content of this attachment or you can visit them all with the corresponding Keys.

A greeting.

Answer (score 0):

use #[key], this will give filename inside foreach statement. 
I am using 3.8 version